# How can I stop two ggplot legends from overlapping?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am making a line graph of TCE concentration in a well over time. The graph has a shaded region, which I created with geom_rect, and a dashed horizontal line, which I created with geom_hline. I want a legend that explains what the shaded region and dotted line mean, in addition to explaining what the line in the line graph means. I have figured out how to do this with the shaded region, and have labeled it "System Operating Period." However, I don't know how to do this for the dashed line. When I set show_guide = FALSE within the geom_hline function,I am able to creat a horizontal line in the legend, but the shaded region and horizontal dashed line overlap in the legend (i.e. the dashed red line sits on top of the box of lavender shading). How can I make a dashed line legend and a shaded region legend that do not overlap? Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(data= Data, aes(x = Date, y = TCE, group = Well, colour = Well)) +
  geom_rect(data = Data, 
            aes(xmin = as.Date("2016-04-01", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                xmax = as.Date("2016-12-31",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf,
                fill = "System Operating Period"),
            linetype = 0,
            alpha = 0.2,
            inherit.aes=FALSE) +
    geom_line(size = 0.75) +
    geom_point()+
    xlab("") + ylab("TCE (ug/L)") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("navy", "#70a845", "#4aac8b", "#7262cd", "#b3923f", "#588ecd", "#cf5a2f", "cadetblue2", "#c1705d", "#c06595", "#c454bc")) +
scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("6 months"),
             date_labels = ("%b %Y")) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1),
      panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major.y = element_line( size=.1, color="gray"),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
      axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black"),
      axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black"),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
      legend.key=element_blank()) +
scale_fill_manual("", breaks = "System Operating Period", values = "lavender") +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=120), colour = "#990000", linetype = "dashed", show_guide = TRUE)
  scale_linetype_manual(labels = "Standard")
```

And here is some of my data:

```
         Date          Well  TCE
208 2012-04-12 Recovery Well  260
209 2012-05-21 Recovery Well 1790
210 2012-06-12 Recovery Well 2160
211 2012-07-20 Recovery Well 1480
212 2012-08-06 Recovery Well 1550
213 2012-09-19 Recovery Well 1170
214 2012-10-03 Recovery Well  782
215 2012-11-14 Recovery Well  989
216 2013-05-09 Recovery Well 1060
217 2013-06-18 Recovery Well 1610
218 2013-07-18 Recovery Well 1540
219 2013-08-16 Recovery Well 1220
220 2013-09-09 Recovery Well 1130
221 2013-10-14 Recovery Well 1040
222 2013-11-12 Recovery Well  834
223 2014-05-23 Recovery Well  869
224 2014-06-18 Recovery Well 1250
225 2014-07-14 Recovery Well  447
226 2014-08-18 Recovery Well  728
227 2014-09-23 Recovery Well  695
228 2014-10-21 Recovery Well  984
229 2014-11-13 Recovery Well  801
230 2015-04-24 Recovery Well  782
231 2015-05-12 Recovery Well 1110
232 2015-06-18 Recovery Well 1030
233 2015-07-10 Recovery Well 1250
234 2015-08-12 Recovery Well 1260
235 2015-09-14 Recovery Well 1090
236 2015-10-02 Recovery Well  943
237 2015-11-04 Recovery Well  735
238 2016-04-14 Recovery Well  806
239 2016-05-02 Recovery Well 1030
240 2016-06-07 Recovery Well  711
241 2016-07-06 Recovery Well  939
242 2016-08-15 Recovery Well  766
243 2016-09-12 Recovery Well  773
244 2016-10-11 Recovery Well  770
245 2016-11-11 Recovery Well  805
246 2016-12-07 Recovery Well  707
```

And here is a picture of the graph I have made:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it through the `linetype` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(data= Data, aes(x = Date, y = TCE, group = Well, colour = Well)) +
    geom_rect(data = Data, 
              aes(xmin = as.Date("2016-04-01", "%Y-%m-%d"),
                  xmax = as.Date("2016-12-31",  "%Y-%m-%d"),
                  ymin = -Inf, 
                  ymax = Inf,
                  fill = "System Operating Period"),
              linetype = 0,
              alpha = 0.2,
              inherit.aes=FALSE) +
    geom_line(size = 0.75) +
    geom_point()+
    xlab("") + ylab("TCE (ug/L)") +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("navy", "#70a845", "#4aac8b", "#7262cd", "#b3923f", "#588ecd", "#cf5a2f", "cadetblue2", "#c1705d", "#c06595", "#c454bc")) +
    scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("6 months"),
                 date_labels = ("%b %Y")) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1),
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_line( size=.1, color="gray"),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
          axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black"),
          axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black"),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
          legend.key=element_blank()) +
    scale_fill_manual("", breaks = "System Operating Period", values = "lavender") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=120, linetype = 'Standard'), colour = "#990000") +
    scale_linetype_manual(NULL, values = 'dashed', labels = "Standard")
```

[image: plot with three legends]

You'll probably want to update order and labels, but it works, at least.